# Can I access related record fields in onclick javascript button?

Tags: javascript, button, onclickjavascript

I have to check a field of a related record in my onclick javascript button.

Is it possible? for instance:

```
var fieldValue = '{!Object__c.LookupField__r.Field__c}'
```

Or is the only alternative to call an apex method to retrieve that value?

I didn't find an answer for this anywhere..

(We have a button for lightning experience, this is for our clients that still use classic)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, and no, you don't need Apex, either. You can use the REST API via the [AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples_asynch.htm) to get the information you want:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/56.0/connection.js")}
sforce.connection.retrieve(
  "LookupField__r.Field__c",
  "Object__c",
  ["{!Object__c.Id}"],
  (result) => {
    console.log(result[0].LookupField__r.Field__c);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought searching for my problem directly would bring up a solution but maybe I should read the documentation on the ajax toolkit.